# i 'm getting Undefined Variable error. and invalid argument supplied for for Here is my controller:

Tags: php

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE StudentID=:student_id' ORDER BY studentID";
  
  $statement = $db->prepare($query);
  ->$statement->bindValue(':student_id',$student_id);
  $statement->execute();
  $student = $statement->fetch();
  $student_name = $student['studentName'];
  $statement->closeCursor();

->foreach ($student as $s)
         {
             echo $s['studentID']."; ";
             echo $s['studentName']."; ";
             echo $s['Email']."<br>\n ";
         }
```

undefined variable
and invalid argument
i tried to delete student_id but still getting error
getting error in foreach i dont know what to use for that

Comment: Seems like $student_id is not defined here, you should define a variables before using it

Comment: Can you help me to solve foreach loop error?

Comment: ->$statement->bindValue(':student_id',$student_id);
If $student_id is not defined you will have an error as you alredy got
Add error_reporting(E_ALL); to the beginning of your script and you will see the real error.